# DataGridView and IEnumerable

Tags: c#, winforms, linq, datagridview, ienumerator

I am using LINQtoCsv (Info [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25133/LINQ-to-CSV-library)), and have hit a snag.

I have an IEnumerable set up like that page says: `IEnumerable<Character> characters = cc.Read<Character>(file, inputFileDescription);`

What I don't know how to do is go from the IEnumerable, to something that will show on the datagridview. I have never used LINQ or IEnumerable before, so sorry if this seems a little stupid.

My code is near identical (names are different obviously) to the way the examples are on the [site](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25133/LINQ-to-CSV-library), so it would be easiest to just pretend that those examples are my code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suspect it's as simple as setting the [`DataSource`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.datasource):

```
view.DataSource = characters;
```

Depending on what LINQ to CSV does, you may want to pull everything into a `List<T>` first:

```
var characters = cc.Read<Character>(file, inputFileDescription).ToList();
view.DataSource = characters;
```

You'll probably want to set the columns etc directly, overriding the descriptive heading etc. Follow the documentation link for lots of examples etc.

Comment: I can not simply do `List<Character> characters = cc.Read<Character>(file, inputFileDescription);` as I get this error:

 `Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<ISK_Helper.Ops.Character>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<ISK_Helper.Ops.Character>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?) ISK-Helper C:\Users\Robert\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\ISK-Helper\ISK-Helper\Ops.cs 60`

Comment: @user1720845: Whoops - I meant to put a `ToList` call in there. I've edited my answer.

Comment: I tried your edit, and I get the following error: `An unhandled exception of type 'LINQtoCSV.NameNotInTypeException' occurred in LINQtoCSV.dll 
Additional information: The input file has column name "EndPay(M) " in the first record, but there is no field or property with that name in type "ISK_Helper.Ops+Character".`  Then it lists the path for file. If you look at the link in the question the first example is a class that defines the headers (Referenced by Read<>)... What is confusing is that that heading is in the file exactly.

Comment: @user1720845: Well that's nothing to do with the code I've shown, nothing to do with the question you've asked, and everything to do with the data. I can't help you with that - if you need more help with it, I suggest you ask a new question including sample data and a short but complete program that fails.

Comment: sorry, yeah, there was a slight formatting issue, it does work!